# Page 404 appears in all routes of React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create the routes of my navbar and I am using React Router but I don't know what I am doing wrong because the 404 page appears in all the routes, even the home one, what could be wrong?

**APP.JS :**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./componentes/Navbar";
import './Estilos/EstilosGlobales.css'
import {ThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import theme from './themeconfig'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Inicio from "./Paginas/Inicio";
import FooterPage from "./componentes/FooterPage";
import AllCategorias from "./Paginas/AllCategorias.jsx"
import ErrorNoFount from "./Paginas/Error404";


function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <>
          <Navbar />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Inicio} />
          <Route path="/categorias" component={AllCategorias} />
          <Route path="*" component={ErrorNoFount} />
          <FooterPage />
          </>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

As you can see, the two components come out of 404 and that of my home.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the wildcard path match `path="*"` as that will apply the `route` to all pages. When you place a `route` with no path attribute below all other `route` statements it acts as a catch; basically, if no routes match show the 404.

from:

```
<Route path="*" component={ErrorNoFount} />
```

to:

```
<Route component={ErrorNoFount} />
```

Comment: I have been able to solve the problem in another way

Answer (score 0):

Try this and solve the problem.

```
<Router>
 <>
  <Navbar />
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/" exact component={Inicio} />
       <Route exact path="/categorias" component={AllCategorias} />
       <Route path="*" component={ErrorNoFount} />
       </Switch>
  <FooterPage />
 </>
</Router>
```

the Switch tag should only contain the Route tags, there cannot be other components like children.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you need anoter /

```
<Router>
 <>
  <Navbar />
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/" exact component={Inicio} />
       <Route exact path="/categorias" component={AllCategorias} />
       <Route path="/*" component={ErrorNoFount} />
       </Switch>
  <FooterPage />
 </>
</Router>
```